# How do I start this proof?

Tags: abstract-algebra

How can I begin proving this? I am not sure where to start.

A(S) is defined to be the set of all bijections from S to S.

[image]

Comment: What is $A(S)$? What kind of algebraic structure?

Comment: A(S) is defined to be the set of all bijections from S to S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof should probably go along the following lines:

First, write out what $f^r$ means: $\ f^r = \underbrace{f...f}_{r \text{ times}}$. So for example
\begin{equation} f^{r}f^{s} = (\underbrace{f...f}_{r \text{ times}})(\underbrace{f...f}_{s \text{ times}}) = \underbrace{f...f}_{r+s \text{ times}} = f^{r+s}.\end{equation}

Comment: It is probably important to note within the proof that you're using the associativity of function composition.